# How to create subfolders in GoogleDrive using python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I want to sync a folder from my local to the folder in Google Drive. My folder structure is

```
Sync
  | -> folders
        | -> james
        | -> content2
```

The script is given below

```
FULL_PATH = 'D://Sync\\folders'
DIR_NAME = 'folders'

def folder_upload(service):
  parents_id = {}

  for root, _, files in os.walk(FULL_PATH, topdown=True):
     last_dir = root.split('/')[-1]
     pre_last_dir = root.split('/')[-2]
     if pre_last_dir not in parents_id.keys():
        pre_last_dir = []
     else:
        pre_last_dir = parents_id[pre_last_dir]

     folder_metadata = {'name': last_dir,
                       'parents': [pre_last_dir],
                       'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
     create_folder = service.files().create(body=folder_metadata,
                                           fields='id').execute()
     folder_id = create_folder.get('id', [])

     for name in files:
        file_metadata = {'name': name, 'parents': [folder_id]}
        media = MediaFileUpload(
            os.path.join(root, name),
            mimetype=mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type(name)[0])
        service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                               media_body=media,
                               fields='id').execute()

    parents_id[last_dir] = folder_id

return parents_id
```

The output i get in google drive is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. In the line root.split('/'), the delimiter has to be `'\\'` not `'\'`.

So, the modified version was `root.split('\\')`.